# How to describe connected and simply connected Lie groups with Lie algebra $[x,y]=v, [x,z]=w, [y,z]=0$, and ${\rm span}(v,w)={\rm span}(y,z)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

I am interested in such problem:

> How to describe connected simple connected Lie groups and connected Lie groups with given finite dimensional Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ ?

---

Suppose that we have real Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ with basis $x, y, z$ and given relations
$$
[x, y] = v, \;\;\; 
[x, z]= w, \;\;\; [y, z] = 0 
$$
Where span($v, w$) = span($y, z$).

I am interested in concrete Lie groups with such algebras, how to describe them in matrix form of like subalgebras of $\mathfrak{gl}_3(\mathbb{R})$? For example, i have $v = 13y + 11z$ and $w = 7y$, how explicitly find such required Lie groups?

Using fundamental Lie's theorem we know that there exits unique connected and simple connected Lie group with such
Lie algebra, but is there any ''$recipe$'' how to construct it?Also i don't even know how many connected Lie groups have such algebra and how to describe them? Is there any hints?I thinks it's very classical problem, but it's rather hard for me. Any help appreciated

Comment: @DietrichBurde i assume that  $v$ and $w$ have such coeffitients, that Jacobi identity is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explicit Lie brackets for the basis $(x,y,z)$ are given by
$$
[x,y]=v=\lambda_1 y+\lambda_2 z,\quad [x,z]=w=\mu_1 y+\mu_2 z
$$
and the other brackets equal to zero.
This is a *family* of Lie algebras consisting of different non-isomorphic Lie algebras. For example for all scalars equal to zero, we obtain the abelian Lie algebra $K^3$ in dimension $3$.
For other choices we obtain the solvable non-nilpotent Lie algebra $K\oplus \mathfrak{r}_2(K)$, or $\mathfrak{r}_3(K)$ or $\mathfrak{r}_{3,\lambda}(K)$, or the nilpotent Heisenberg Lie algebra $\mathfrak{n}_3(K)$. In all cases the connected, simply connected Lie group having this Lie algebra is uniquely determined (assuming $K=\Bbb R$).

Comment: What is $\mathfrak{n}_3(K)$ and $\mathfrak{r}_2(K)$?Sorry, i am not much familiar with this notions, also i am interested in concrete Lie groups with such algebras, how to describe them in matrix form of like subalgebras of $\mathfrak{gl}_3(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: See [here](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_70_lie_algebra_course.pdf) for the notations of the $3$-dimensional Lie algebras, section$1.7$, the classification in low dimension. Use the exponential map for matrices of the Lie groups.

Comment: Thanks for help!